# square free polynomials

Tags: calculus, polynomials

How can we prove that a polynomial $P(x)$ is square-free? Numerically, I think I can argue that if there is no multiple roots, then it should be square free. But is there any other formal way to check it?

Comment: Compute the gcd of the polynomial and its derivative, which you can do without computing roots using Euclid's algorithm. Remember that a root of a polynomial is multiple if and only if it is also a root of the derivative.

Comment: How will gcd and its derivative help me to conclude such an argument? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I was adding it above. Have you seen the property that I mentioned above?

Comment: So, suppose that I have 20th degree polynomial, then will I take derivative and find the roots of 19th degree polynomials, and then what?

Comment: No, no roots are computed. Compute the [gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor) of $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$, which if computed using Euclid's algorithm only involves a few polynomial long divisions. The gcd is going to have positive degree if and only if $p(x)$ has multiple roots.

Comment: I see, if gcd is bigger than 1, then this root is shared by both and hence it would be multiple root. So, I do not need to calculate roots of the original polynomials, right?

Comment: Yes, and not only that. The gcd is going to be the product of all factors $(x-r)$ raised to one less than the multiplicity of the root $r$ of $p(x)$. I am making this observation because it is useful to do $p(x)/\gcd(p(x),p'(x))$ and obtain the square-free part of $p(x)$.

Comment: For example, if $p(x)=x^3 - 3 x - 2$, then $p'(x)=3x^2 - 3$ and $\gcd(p(x),p'(x))=x+1$. Then $p(x)/\gcd(p(x),p'(x))=x^2-x-2$, which has all the same roots are $p(x)$ but all with multiplicity $1$.

Comment: In other words, if $p(x)=f(x)^2g(x)$, then $p'(x)=f(x)\cdot (2f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x))$